# Batch File:: Write Special characters to text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, echo

I'm trying to print special characters to a text file.

Those are my problematic lines :

```
(
echo FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,3) DO (
echo echo "%~f0" myText
echo )
) > myFile.bat
```

I tried to escape the special characters with `^` and with `\` but seems like it's not working properly

I tried :

1.

```
(echo FOR \/L \%\%A IN (1,1,3) DO \() >> myFile.bat
```

2.

```
(echo FOR ^/L ^%^%A IN (1,1,3) DO ^() >> myFile.bat
```

3.

```
(echo echo \"%~f0\" myText) >> myFile.bat
```

4.

```
(echo echo ^"%~f0\^" myText) >> myFile.bat
```

None of them is working properly.
I was wondering if there is a command like in php

```
$myText = <<<EOF

EOF;
```

That would magically do the task but if not ...

Comment: `^` escapes most special characters. `%` however is escaped by `%`. "properly" in this case means "as I expect". Please tell us what your expectations were and what actually happened.

Comment: try `%%` to escape.

Comment: Your main problem is that you need to escape any closing parentheses before the last closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need to do:

```bat
(
    echo FOR /L %%%%A IN (1,1,3^) DO (
    echo    echo "%%~f0" myText
    echo ^)
)>myFile.cmd
```

Escape the intenal closing parentheses with the standard circumflex character, escape each percent with another.

Comment: I did not find that I needed to double up on percents.

Comment: Your system must be magic then because without doubling the percents you should have; line1-`FOR /L %A IN (1,1,3) DO (` and line2-`echo "X:\MyPath\aBatch.cmd" myText`.